# Keep ggplot secondary axis scale fixed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a ggplot with a secondary axis using the `sec_axis()` function but am having trouble retaining the correct scale.

Below is a reproducible example

```
# load package 

library(ggplot2)

# produce dummy data    

data = data.frame(week = 1:5,
                  count = c(45, 67, 21, 34, 50),
                  rate = c(3, 6, 2, 5, 3))

# calculate scale (and save as an object called 'scale')

scale = max(data$count)/10

# produce ggplot 

p = ggplot(data, aes(x = week)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = count), stat = "identity") +
  geom_point(aes(y = rate*scale)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scale, name = "% positive", 
                                         breaks = seq(0, 10, 2)))

# look at ggplot - all looks good

p

# change the value of the scale object 

scale = 2

# look at ggplot - you can see the scale has now change 

p
```

In reality I am producing a series of ggplot's within a loop and within each iteration of the loop the 'scale' object changes

## Question

How do I ensure the scale of my secondary y-axis remains fixed? (even if the value of the 'scale' object changes)

## EDIT

I wanted to keep the example as simple as possible (see example above) but on request I'll add an example which includes a loop

```
# load package 

library(ggplot2)

# produce dummy data    

data = data.frame(group = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5)),
                  week = rep(1:5, 2),
                  count = c(45, 67, 21, 34, 50,
                            120, 200, 167, 148, 111),
                  rate = c(3, 6, 2, 5, 3,
                           15, 17, 20, 11, 12))

# define the groups i want to loop over 

group = c("A", "B")

# initalize an empty list (to store figures)

fig_list = list()

for(i in seq_along(group)){

  # subset the data 

  data.sub = data[data$group == group[i], ]

  # calculate scale (and save as an object called 'scale')

  scale = max(data.sub$count)/20

  # produce the plot 

  p = ggplot(data.sub, aes(x = week)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = count), stat = "identity") +
    geom_point(aes(y = rate*scale), size = 4, colour = "dark red") + 
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scale, name = "% positive", 
                                           breaks = seq(0, 20, 5))) + 
    ggtitle(paste("Plot", group[i]))

  # print the plot 

  print(p)

  # store the plot in a list 

  fig_list[[group[i]]] = p

}
```

I get the following figures when printing within the loop (everything looks good)

[image: loop_print_A]

[image: loop_print_B]

However... if I call the figure for group A from the list I created you can see the secondary y-axis scale is now incorrect (it has used the scale created for group B)

```
fig_list[["A"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what you want. The secondary axis is defined as `y/scale`, so of course it will change when you change the object `scale`. Maybe you need two objects for "scale", or just hard-code the value, like in `sec_axis(~./6.7, ...)`?

Comment: As I am producing numerous plots within a loop hard coding will not work - I want to keep the y-axis scale fixed for each plot generated within the loop (and not change on the next iteration of the loop)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is still unclear to me. Maybe create an example including the loop and examples on how the plots should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your edit, this makes things clearer. Your problem stems from the way R evaluates objects. The plot in your `fig_list` is not an image, but an outline on how the plot should be generated. It is only generated when you call `print` (by typing `fig_list["A"]`and hitting enter). Since the value for `scale` changes throughout the loop, if you evaluate the plot later, it will be incorrect, since it will use the last iteration of `scale`.

An easy solution is to wrap your code for plotting in a function and use `lapply`:

```r
make_plot <- function(df) {

  scale = max(df$count)/20

  ggplot(df, aes(x = week)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = count), stat = "identity") +
    geom_point(aes(y = rate*scale), size = 4, colour = "dark red") + 
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scale, name = "% positive", 
                                           breaks = seq(0, 20, 5))) + 
    ggtitle(paste("Plot", unique(df$group)))
}

grouped_data <- split(data, data$group)
fig_list <- lapply(grouped_data, make_plot)
```

Now when you call the first plot, it is evaluated correctly.

```r
fig_list["A"]
#> $A
```

[image]

This still works when you happen to have an object `scale` with a bogus value in your environment, since R looks up `scale` within the function call, and not in the global environment.

Created on 2018-09-02 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).